# PHP database syntax error

Tags: php

Hi I am new to php programming and tried to create a encrypted password but the problem is it always generate the same md5 for different passwords and I can't log in using the login.php Here is my code

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

if($name && $password){

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error);
    mysql_select_db("myfirstdatabase") or die(mysql_error);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE name='$name'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

     if ($numrows != 0){

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
             $dbname = $row['name'];
             $dbpassword = $row['password'];

            }
                if ($name==$dbname){
                    if($password==$dbpassword){

                        header("location: users.php");

                    }else {
                        echo "Your password is incorrect!";
                    }
                }else{

                        echo "Your name is incorrect!";
                }





        }else {
            echo "Name is not registered!";
        }

    }else{

        echo "You have to type a name and password";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Using `md5` unsalted to "hash" passwords, using `mysql_*` functions... What is this, 2005?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite new to programming and I am studying from the source I got.

Comment: Your source is bad. You should find a more recent one. For starters, use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password-hash) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password-verify) to do passwords. Not `md5`. That stuff hasn't been secure in years.

Comment: Ok thank you, Now I know why it in't working. I will try to find a recent source.

Comment: The password is only one problem - as I mentioned initially, `mysql_*` functions are outdated and vulnerable. In your code above, I could submit my name as `' or sleep(100000); -- ` and submit it a bunch of times to easily DoS or crash your server. You should use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared queries. It's a bit of a learning curve but you'll be much safer.

Comment: Also, comparing strings with `==` leads to some interesting security problems.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Anant It works! I will try to use this as reference Thank you!

Comment: @Anant How can I do that? Sorry I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You have to do it like below:-***

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);// show all errors
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myfirstdatabase");
    if($conn){
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,md5($_POST['password']));
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE name= $name AND password = $password");
        if(mysqli_num_row($query)>0){           
            header("location: users.php");   
        }else {
            echo "user name or password is incorrect!";
        }
    }else{
        echo "deb connection error:-".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
}else{
   echo "Please fill form fully";
}
?>
```

***Suggestions:-***

1.Don't use  `mysql_*`(deprecated from php5.5 onward  and removed from php7). Use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

2.Use password hasing mechanism instead of `md5`.

3.Use `prepared` statements of `mysqli` or `PDO` to prevent your code from `SQL Injection`.